# Upload file error handling using URLSessionConfiguration.background and uploadTask

Tags: ios, swift, http, urlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I am using URLSessionConfiguration.background and uploadTask to upload a file from an iOS app.

The upload session is configured in the following way:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.mycompany.myapp.fileUploader")
configuration.isDiscretionary = false
configuration.allowsCellularAccess = true
uploadURLSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
```

and the request is:

```
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/octect-stream", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


let task = uploadURLSession.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: fileURL)
```

I'd like to understand how to manage the error handling.

How the http errors 4xx or 5xx are handled by the URLSession.uploadTask?

How can I trigger the retrying on 5xx errors?

Comment: It's handled in the delegate method `urlSession(_:task:didCompleteWithError:)`. I'm not sure that a 400 HTTP error results into an `error`, you might need to check `(task.response as? HTTPURLResponse).statusCodeCode`

Comment: I can confirm that the 4xx http errors do not result as an error from the task point of view in urlSession(_:task:didCompleteWithError:) delegate callback. I am still investigating about 5xx errors. The http response  status code can be obtained from the task casting the task response as you have specified.

Comment: Also the 5xx errors are handled by the task as a success. I am pretty confused about how I can handle the retrying defining a decent back-off policy. I guess that I could create a brand new upload task but I will cause and infinite loop of 5xx errors :-)

Comment: You need to retry count per request. In URLSession with callback (not in foreground), I think it's the same, the `error` is more about "No connected", and other internal error, not about HTTP statuses.

Comment: I was expecting something more similar to android worker but definitely it is not the case :-(

Comment: That's a reason why Alamofire is popular (error in case of HTTP codes, retry, etc.), but it doesn't manage Background...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLSession.uploadTask does not handle the http server side errors. It handles retrying and errors only for client side or network issues.

The http status/error has to be retrieved from the task response casting it to an HTTPURLResponse.

Directly from the uploadTask call (not supported by background URLSession):

```
let task = uploadSession?.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: fileURL, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Upload error:\(error)")
        //Client side error
        return
    }
    
    guard let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
        print("Upload completed with response:\(response.description ?? "undefined")")
        //It should not happen at all
        return
    }
    
    if (200...299).contains(res.statusCode) {
        print("Upload completed successfully. Status code:\(res.statusCode)")
    }
    else if (400...499).contains(res.statusCode) {
        print("Upload fatal issue. Status code:\(res.statusCode)")
        //Fatal issue, do not retry the upload
    }
    else if (500...599).contains(res.statusCode) {
        print("Upload issue. Status code:\(res.statusCode)")
        //Schedules a new uploading task for the file
    }
    else {
        print("Upload completed with status code:\(res.statusCode)")
    }
})
```

or, if you are using a background URLSession, from the URLSessionTaskDelegate:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Upload error:\(error)")
        //Client side error
        return
    }

    guard let res = task.response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
        print("Upload completed with response:\(task.response?.description ?? "undefined")")
        //It should not happen at all
        return
    }

    if (200...299).contains(res.statusCode) {
        print("Upload completed successfully. Status code:\(res.statusCode)")
    }
    else if (400...499).contains(res.statusCode) {
        print("Upload fatal issue. Status code:\(res.statusCode)")
        //Fatal issue, do not retry the upload
    }
    else if (500...599).contains(res.statusCode) {
        print("Upload issue. Status code:\(res.statusCode)")
        //Schedules a new uploading task for the file
    }
    else {
        print("Upload completed with status code:\(res.statusCode)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know at what stage it's safe to delete the file after creating the `uploadTask(fromFile:...)`? No documentation to say whether you have to wait until notified via `URLSessionTaskDelegate`.

Comment: @Nestor For sure you can delete the file as soon as the URLSessionTaskDelegate didCompleteWithError has fired. In my use case I delete the file only for 2xx or 4xx response codes, for the 5xx responses I will re-trigger a new upload.

Answer (score 2):

Create the upload task like this:

```
let task = uploadSession?.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: fileURL, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Upload error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("Response status code: \(response.statusCode)")
            }
        }
    })

    task?.resume()
```

you can handle errors and responsecode in the callback ☝️, alternatively
you can look at [`URLSessionTaskDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate) and and [`URLSessionDataDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate) for a fine-grained control over the upload task.

Comment: I cannot use the uploadTask with the completionHandler because I am using the background URLSession, see URLSessionConfiguration.background in configuration. I am investigating about the delegate...

Comment: I've try using urlSession(_:task:didCompleteWithError:) in URLSessionTaskDelegate and it provides the response information inside the task